# postMessage not declared in this scope error when building nativeClient plugin

Tags: google-nativeclient

When I am trying to build the plugin module using .\scons it is raising me errors. What might cause these types of errors...? Error is

```
 postMessage() was not declared in this scope.
```

I am using pepper_16 version. Here is the procee I did

1. Installed Python and gave the path required(Installed in D drive as I do not have privileges).
2. Downloaded nacl_sdk.zip extracted in the same folder where I have installed python and updated the tools with nacl_sdk.bat update
3. Enabled NativeClient form about:flags window and executed the server using httpd.py file.
4. And created project in Pepper_16/examples/TestApp using init_project.
5. Written the code as it is in the Getting started tutorial to test.
6. Then using ./scons in the same project folder in cmd mode I have tried to build 
   The above process worked fine for me where I have admin privileges. But the same procedure and same code not working where I do not have admin privileges.

Please let me know if any further details are required.

Answer (score 0):

which source file was being compiled?  a lengthier cut-n-paste of the output around the error message would help to give context.

also, when you say the plugin module, are you referring to NaCl itself or your own PPAPI plugin?  normally NaCl's plugin is built into Chromium using gyp, and while scons can be used to build the NaCl plugin it is typically only used for testing, via the --register-pepper-plugin command line argument to chrome.

Comment: I am running the application like ./scons in project folder. Is there any alternative for this?

Comment: please give more detail.  here are some guesses:  you downloaded the native client SDK.  or you downloaded the native client project itself (typically not necessary for developing NaCl apps).  both use scons, though in the former case it is perfectly reasonable (relatively easy) to use other build systems such as make.